# Using taxonomy term value as title for the view

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I created a taxonomy, called `Galleries` for images on the web site:

1. Our Rooms
2. Our Food and wines
3. Our Services

Then I created a gallery for each of the terms, using views. I wanted to override the title of gallery to the term value, as it is shown in this subform for Contextual filters:

[image]

But the id of term is used in the url:

http://hotelcentralpark.ro/gallery/1

http://hotelcentralpark.ro/gallery/2

etc

So, instead of words: "Our Rooms", "Our Food and wines" I get "1" and "2", if I check the box "Override title".

How can I show the value of the term instead of it's id? But keep id in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the function, using [hook_views_pre_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

```
function custom_views_pre_render($view) {
      if ($view->name == 'gallery') {
            // get the $tid from the view's args
            $term = taxonomy_term_load( $view->args[0] );
            if( $term ){
                  $view->build_info['title'] = $term->name;
            }
      }
}
```

Mind, that in Drupal 7 drupal_set_title doesn't work for views:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343623/drupal-7-drupal-set-title-not-working-in-views

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the hook_views_pre_render on your view to override the page title

```
function custom_views_pre_render($view) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view_name') {
    // get the $tid from the view's args
    $term = taxonomy_get_term( $view->args[0] );
    if( $term ){
      drupal_set_title( $term->name );
    }
  }
}
```